# Grab data from Mysql and loop through results

Tags: mysql, vb.net, loops, datareader

I need to check a mysql table periodically and if there are any rows found, I need to loop through them and perform some actions.

My SQL string is nice and simple: "SELECT * FROM 'dbcpman_jobs'".

There could be 1 returned row, or there could be 20 returned rows.
For each returned row, I need to assign some of the data to variables...

```
            Dim job_id As String = jobrow.Item("id")
            Dim job_jobid As String = jobrow.Item("jobid")
            Dim job_status As String = jobrow.Item("status")
            Dim job_dbxid As String = jobrow.Item("dbxid")
```

Then i need to make an API call using the information that's just been split out...

```
            Try
                Dim jobapicall As New System.Net.WebClient
                jobcheckresult = jobapicall.DownloadString(fulljobapicheckurl)
                Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine("Error 'DBX-Err-1' - Error during API call")
            End Try
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to loop through all rows found?

My code currently checks the first item found only, which is not ideal as if that job fails, everything else gets held up.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you storing the data that is returned by the query? I mean is it DataTable or a custom object? Can you also share the code that you are currently using to check the first item only?

Comment: I have solved this with a for each loop. Indeed it was a datatable.

Answer (score 0):

FOR EACH loop was the answer.

something like this...

```
For Each jobRow As DataRow in dtJobResults.Rows

Try

what I want to do for each returned row. 

Catch Ex as exception
messagebox.show("Oh no, something went wrong!")


End Try

Next
```